# How to fix this code in order to perform "Division by using Subtracting"

Tags: assembly, division, subtraction, masm32

My program's supposed to perform division by using subtraction. However, I'm getting nonsense results as output. Could someone help me with my procedure and the loop within? 
Thank you.

```
div proc
pushad

mov ecx,firstInt
mov ebx,0
subtracting:
    sub ebx,secondInt
loop subtracting
mov divResult,ebx
popad
ret
divt endp
```

Comment: You are supposed to check whether the number is large enough so you can subtract.

Comment: Can you give me an example how to do that?

Comment: If you're trying to calculate 'divResult = firstInt / secondInt' you are supposed to subtract from firstInt, not from 0. (I will not write the code for you).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You continu subtracting for as long as there is no borrow. If a borrow happened, you have the count:

```
    mov     ecx, firstInt
    mov     ebx, -1
subtracting:
    inc     ebx
    sub     ecx, secondInt
    jnb     subtracting
    mov     divResult, ebx
```

**EDIT**

What the above code still lacks is checking if the divider is zero. If we allow a zero-divider the code will run forever because subtracting zero will never produce a borrow!

This simple solution gets the job done, but it is unacceptably slow for big quotients. This calls for a better solution without betraying of course the task of "Division by using subtracting" aka "Don't use `div` (or any similar instruction)".

In order to mimic the `div` instruction:

```
divide:
    mov     eax, firstInt
    xor     edx, edx
    div     secondInt       ; -> EDX is remainder, EAX is quotient
```

we can write:

```
simple:
    mov     edx, firstInt
    mov     eax, -1
.A: inc     eax
    sub     edx, secondInt
    jnb     .A
    add     edx, secondInt  ; -> EDX is remainder, EAX is quotient
```

The problem with this simple solution is that we could be subtracting a small number many, many times. What if we could find a way to subtract more at once?
We can, if we subtract binary multiples of the divider (*1, *2, *4, *8, *16, ...). It will be the summing of these factors that produces the quotient.

To calculate e.g. `503 / 20` we would subtract the following:

```
503 - (20 * 16) = 183
183 - (20 *  8) =  23
 23 - (20 *  1) =   3 <-- is remainder
            --
            25 <-- is quotient
```

In code:

```
complex:
    mov     edx, firstInt
    xor     eax, eax
    jmp     .C
.A: rol     ecx, 1
    shl     ebx, 1
    jc      .B
    cmp     ebx, edx
    jbe     .A
.B: rcr     ebx, 1
    add     eax, ecx
    sub     edx, ebx
.C: mov     ebx, secondInt
    mov     ecx, 80000000h
    cmp     edx, ebx
    jnb     .A
; -> EDX is remainder, EAX is quotient
```

To illustrate the importance of developing a better solution, I've timed a few divisions:

```
                       simple      complex    divide
                   --------------  --------  --------
4294967295 /   1   8087730.0 µsec  3.0 µsec  0.3 µsec
2147483648 /  10    405994.0 µsec  1.3 µsec  0.1 µsec
     47623 / 320         0.4 µsec  0.2 µsec  0.1 µsec
```

- `4294967295 /   1` is the worst case division
- `2147483648 /  10` is used to start displaying the number 2147483648
- `47623 / 320` is used to convert a 320x200 256-color video mode offset address 47623 into (x,y) coordinates

Comment: Where's the init for `ecx` in `complex`?  Is that the divisor?

Comment: @PeterCordes The `ECX` register is initialized at *complex.C* (line 14). `ECX` plays the role of binary multiple of the divider (more exactly its factor). In the example I gave it becomes 16, 8, and 1 yielding a total of 25 which is the quotient.

Comment: Oh, I missed that the loop started with a `jmp` to the bottom where there's a `mov ecx, 80000000h`.  Derp.